# How I can simplify this inequality or how I can solve it?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, special-functions

How I can simplify this inequality or how I can solve it:

$$\left\lceil\dfrac{\ln(t+2)}{\ln 2}\right\rceil-\left\lfloor\dfrac{\ln(t+1)}{\ln2}\right\rfloor>1$$
where $t$ is a positive integer.

Here $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ are respectively the **Ceiling** and the **Floor** functions.

I have no idea to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This equality is equivalent to this statement:

> There is an integer $n$ strictly between $\log_2(t+1)$ and $\log_2(t+2)$

And this is the same as

> $t+1< 2^n<t+2$

This happens if and only if $\lceil t+1\rceil $ is a power of $2$ and $t\notin\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @ ajotatxe: Why you add the last condition in the last line!

Comment: @DER If $t$ is integer and $\lceil t+1\rceil=2^n$ then $t+1=2^n$, that is, the power of two is not *strictly* between $t+1$ and $t+2$.